# How should Transactions be handled in the context of DDD

Tags: architecture, transactions, domain-driven-design, software-design, unit-of-work

In the context of DDD where should a transaction begin and end, when you deal with Domain Events ?

Infrastructure.Layer has the UoW implementation

```
/// => configured via DI as Per Request
class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
     ITransaction _transaction;
     static ISessionFactory _factory; 
     ISession _session

     UnitOfWork()
     {
         _session = _factory.OpenSession();
         _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();  ///=> start transaction 
     }

     void Commit()
     {
          try
             _transaction.Commit();
          catch
            _transaction.Rollback(); 
          finally
            Dispose();
     } 
}
```

Application.Layer UseCase Handler

```
class SomeAppServiceUseCaseHandler : IUseCaseHandler
{
      IUnitOfWork _uow;
      ISomeRepo _repo;

      AppService(IUnitOfWork uow, ISomeRepo repo)
      {
          _uow = uow;
          _repo = repo;
      }

      void UseCaseHandler(Request request)
      {

         SomeAggregate agg = _repo.GetAggregate(request.Id) 

                       agg.DoSomethingToChangeState();

         _repo.UpdateAgg(agg);

         _uow.Commit(agg);  ///=> commit changes for this transaction success
      }
}
```

and in the Domain.Layer having the method which will also add a Domain.Event to a list of domain events for the aggregate.

```
SomeAggregate : AggregateRoot
{
   DoSomethingToChangeState()
   {
       .... do something

       var someObject;
       base.AddEvent(new SomethingHappenedEvent(someObject)));
   }
}
```

Application.Layer has the Domain.Event handlers

```
class SomethingHappenedEventHander : Handler<SomethingHappenedEvent>
{
    IRepo repo;
    IUnitOfWork _uow;

    DomainEventHander(IRepo repo, IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _uow= uow;
    }

    HandleEvent(someObject)
    {
         AnotherAggregate agg = new AnotherAggregate ();
                          agg.DoSomeCommand(someObject);

         _repo.Create(agg);
         _uow.Commit();  ///=> commit changes for same transaction fail, should rollback prev transaction as well
    }
}
```

I feel this is not right

1. Who should publish the event ? from what I see, the UoW should do so in the Commit() method, but I don't think this is right, I fell that the UoW shouldn't do that, but I cannot see who else could.
2. If at some point in the chain something fails, I have already committed some data, which most likely I would not want to do if something along the way fail.

So how should the two situations be handled the right way ?

Comment: DDD states that only one Aggregate should be modified per transaction.

Comment: Yes that is true, but how should multiple Aggregates update be handled then ? I don't think that I should begin a transaction within the Application.Layer UseCaseHandler

Comment: in a Saga/Process manager. If you need to rollback an Aggregate then something is wrong with the boundaries or you need to model this as a business process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Constantin, only one Aggregate should be updated per command. Why? Because by updating more than one aggregate in a transaction, you reduce the throughput of the system. The larger your database transaction boundaries, the more likely it will be that you face contention when writing data so you want to keep your transactions as fine grained as possible.

Regarding your questions:

1. UnitOfWork can certainly save the changes. Alternatively, your Repo class can do the same with a new method, IRepo.Save(Aggregate):

   ```
   _repo.Save(agg);
   ```
2. Your concern is valid. You can (and possibly should), move your UnitOfWork out of the scope of the Handler/UseCaseHandler level so that you don't have this boilerplate code of committing the UoW in every handler. Then, you can save both of your aggregates in one database transaction. A better approach would be to employ an architecture that allows you to recover from failures. You could:

   1. Handle the command and generate events in an event store. (UoW will do this)
   2. Poll for new events in the event store and publish them to a queue.
   3. Read events from the queue and dispatch them to any Handler that is registered.
   4. Save new events in the event store (again with UoW) and the process would repeat.

   If any of the steps above fails, processing would pick up from that point and ensure that the work is done. With this approach, your application is more resilient and transaction boundaries are correctly applied.